# Get the last element of a std::string

Tags: c++, string

I was wondering if there's an abbreviation or a more elegant way of getting the last character of a string like in:

```
char lastChar = myString.at( myString.length() - 1 );
```

Something like `myString.back()` doesn't seem to exist. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: I think it's not necessary, cause you can do that pretty easily with provided functions.

Comment: That argument would hold for the container classes as well.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

In C++11 and beyond, you can use the `back` member function:

```
char ch = myStr.back();
```

In C++03, `std::string::back` is not available due to an oversight, but you can get around this by dereferencing the `reverse_iterator` you get back from `rbegin`:

```
char ch = *myStr.rbegin();
```

In both cases, be careful to make sure the string actually has at least one character in it! Otherwise, you'll get *undefined behavior*, which is a Bad Thing.

Comment: a back() function has been added in C++11

Comment: @eddi- Thanks for pointing that out!  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Note: I had to force g++ to compile with `--std=c++11` for `back()` to be available.

Comment: @JulianHarty That's true for most C++11 features, I believe. :-)

Answer (score 23):

You probably want to check the length of the string first and do something like this:

```
if (!myStr.empty())
{
    char lastChar = *myStr.rbegin();
}
```

Comment: You don't have to check the length.  If it is the empty string, you just get '\0' stored into lastChar.

Comment: @MarkLoeser: That is not true. `*myStr.end()` is not the same as `myStr[myStr.size()]`! And, even if it were, `myStr.rbegin()` is equivalent to `myStr.end()-1`, which is plainly invalid on an empty string.

Answer (score 7):

You could write a function template `back` that delegates to the member function for ordinary containers and a normal function that implements the missing functionality for strings:

```
template <typename C>
typename C::reference back(C& container)
{
    return container.back();
}

template <typename C>
typename C::const_reference back(const C& container)
{
    return container.back();
}

char& back(std::string& str)
{
    return *(str.end() - 1);
}

char back(const std::string& str)
{
    return *(str.end() - 1);
}
```

Then you can just say `back(foo)` without worrying whether `foo` is a string or a vector.

Answer (score 2):

`*(myString.end() - 1)` maybe? That's not exactly elegant either.

A python-esque `myString.at(-1)` would be asking too much of an already-bloated class.

Comment: if string is empty it would throw