# std::string::back()

Tags: c++, string, stl, stdstring

Why isn't there a `std::basic_string<...>::back()` member function?

The functionality is obviously there, I mean, one can write

- `myString[myString.size()-1]`
- `*myString.rbegin()`

Am I assuming some wrong equivalence between the potential `back()` and the two methods above? You can say that my second version is concise enough, but then, why not provide a function which is trivial to implement which brings string one step closer to a container? Is there a caveat I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the last element of a std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884548/get-the-last-element-of-a-stdstring)

Comment: Also, I just googled `std::string::back` and this question popped up first...

Comment: But why? What reasonable purpose (you suppose) would it serve to?

Comment: @Xeo: Obviously I know how to get the last element in a string. I am asking why there isn't a function named `back`. What negative implication would it have? You might close it as not a real question, but this is in no way a  duplicate

Comment: @vines: it would have the purpose of being more uniform with containers

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Ah. I've always wondered why string isn't a container too...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no particular reason that `std::string` shouldn't have had these functions and this assertion is supported by the fact that they have been added in the upcoming C++ standard.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just MSVC? Is it really in the standard draft?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at n3290.pdf (FDIS).

Answer (score 2):

If the C++0x standard (or at least the working draft) is to be believed, then `front()` and `back()` do indeed now exist.

See section 21.4.5.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN says that there [is one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404857.aspx). And an accompanying [front()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404773.aspx). Maybe you just have an ancient, doddery compiler.

Comment: MSVC9.0 is an ancient doddery compiler?

Comment: In the MSDN link, you can see that this documentation exists only for VS 2010 (otherwise you could toggle the version). It seems like those two functions were recently added.