# How do I get the last character of a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm using c++ for my program, and I'm pretty good at c++. I have read [Get the last element of a std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884548/get-the-last-element-of-a-stdstring), but none of them helped. My code is:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string str = "Hello World!";
        char endch = str.back();
        if ( endch == "!" ) // Here's the error
        {
            cout << "Found!" << endl;
        } else
        {
            ; // ; alone does nothing
        }
    }
```

Here are the errors

C:\Users\...\Desktop\main.cpp|30|warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]|

C:\Users\...\Desktop\main.cpp|30|error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'm guessing it's the `str.back;`.If you know what the problem is, please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are comparing the char with the string literal. Try

```
if ( endch == '!' )
```

Because

```
"!" // <--- is a string literal.
'!' // <--- it is a character.
```

Answer (score 3):

`endch` is a char. Meanwhile `"!"` is a char array. So `==` doesn't apply.

Use `'!'` instead of `"!"`.

Answer (score 1):

You get a character into `endch`. So compare with a character literal, not a string literal.

```
if ( endch == '!' )
```